# How to deal with label switching issues with Matlab's classification trees?

Tags: classification, dataset, matlab

I have a situation that seems trivial but I can't figure it out. I have a dataset in Matlab that has categorical values. For example:

```
Outlook,Temperature,Humidity,Windy,Play
sunny,hot,high,false,no
sunny,hot,high,true,no
overcast,hot,high,false,yes
rainy,mild,high,false,yes
rainy,cool,normal,false,yes
rainy,cool,normal,true,no
overcast,cool,normal,true,yes
```

In order to use `ClassificationTree` (or other algorithm in machine learning), I need to convert the dataset to a matrix. I use (assuming that data contains the dataset):

```
double(data)
```

which assigns numbers to the values. Let's say `rainy=1`, `overcast=2`, `sunny=3` and so on. I train the ClassificationTree and it works fine. But here is my problem. If I want to predict on test data:

```
overcast,cool,normal,false,yes
```

I need to know the numbers that `double()` assigned to each of the categories. i.e. `overcast=2`. Using `double()` on the test set does not work because there is no guarantee that the numbers assigned by `double()` are the same to those assigned to the training dataset.

I have found a really twisted way of doing it. For example, for `Outlook`:

```
d = zeros(size(test));
ls = getlevels(training.Outlook);
n = size(ls,2);
for i = 1:n
    d(test.Outlook == ls(i),1) = i;
end
```

This will assign the numbers correctly because I check against each of the values for `Outlook` that I found in the training dataset. This is far from elegant, and there has to be something better.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should ask at StackOverflow, since it's a programming issue.

Comment: Drop Matlab and use a language/tool having actual factor variables (like, for instance, R)?

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes, I love this one. I am not 100% sure, but most probably `double(data)` actually calls `grp2idx`, and that's one crazy function http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/grp2idx.html. Every time I hit this function (e.g. every time I call `crosstab`), it drives me nuts, and I end up doing somethings really awkward, although not as twisted as your code.

The best way I found around this is to avoid `grp2idx` entirely by prescribing my own order of labels; see, for example, the options for `ordinal` http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/ordinal.html -- you can prescribe the labels and the order.

The details will depend on how exactly you build that dataset, but the point is -- instead of letting things happen and then using `getlevels`, prescribe the levels yourself. It will still be less nice than you'd like it to be, but nowhere near the level of that `for` loop of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the machine learning algorithms in Statistics Toolbox provide explicit support for categorical inputs.  For example, the "fitensemble" function supports an input argument named "CategoricalPredictors"

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/fitensemble.html

It's probably not a good idea to hand numerical values for categorical data.  If you do need to do something like this it would be a good idea to code these using dummy variables.

Comment: Well, ClassificationTree for example requires a matrix of numeric values. Information about conversion class-number is lost. Hence my question. But I just decided to use my option.